# How can I parse a div and get every <strong> tag content in different rows?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a recipe site which has its ingredients grouped into separate categories, described by the `<strong>` tag in HTML as shown below:

```
<div class="opskriften">
<p class="h3">Ingrediensliste</p>
<p></p>
<p><strong>Påskeæg med nougat (6 stk)</strong><br>150 g. marcipan <br>ca. 40 g. nougat<br>150 g. mørk chokolade <br>50 g. lys chokolade &nbsp;</p>
```

I managed to get the ingredients separated into different columns for the amount, unit and ingredient, but I am finding trouble trying to make another column for the content inside the `<strong>` tags.

This is the code that I used.

```
ingredients = soup.find('div', class_='opskriften')      

#if len(ingredients.find_all('strong'))>0:
s = f"{ingredients}"
r = re.compile(r"(?P<amount>\d+)\s+(?P<unit>\w+.)\s+(?P<ingredient>.+?(?=<))")
df = pd.DataFrame([m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(s)])

with open("somefile.csv", 'w') as fh:
    df.to_csv(fh)
```

I tried playing around with the RegEx but couldn't find any solution to make it work.

[image of what the website I am scraping off looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WjIF.png)

Comment: Can you share url and what example output row would look like?

Comment: Totally. The site is http://www.mummum.dk. The expected output would be these 4 rows: amount // unit // ingredient // group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i have some suggestions for you. There might be problem with parsing due to language that's why the opening of br tags is getting eliminated

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup_chunk = '''<div class="opskriften">
<p class="h3">Ingrediensliste</p>
<p></p>
<p><strong>Påskeæg med nougat (6 stk)</strong><br>150 g. marcipan <br>ca. 40 g. nougat<br>150 g. mørk chokolade <br>50 g. lys chokolade &nbsp;</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_chunk,'lxml')
requiredData = []
for tags in soup.find_all('p'):
    if tags.select('br'):
        contents = {}
        contents['MainItem'] = tags.select('strong')[0].text
        [i.decompose() for i in tags.select('strong')]
        contents['SubItems'] = [i.strip().replace("</p>",'') for i in str(tags).split("<br/>") if "<p>" not in i]
        requiredData.append(contents)
print(requiredData)
```

I put the output in list of dict, so it can be used by anywhere.

```
[{'MainItem': 'Påskeæg med nougat (6 stk)', 'SubItems': ['150 g. marcipan', 'ca. 40 g. nougat', '150 g. mørk chokolade', '50 g. lys chokolade']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of the `div`'s *look* the same you can parse the ingredients with BeautifulSoup.  This relies on a `<strong>` tag being a child of the `<p>` tag that contains all the ingredients:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

s = '''<div class="opskriften">
<p class="h3">Ingrediensliste</p>
<p></p>
<p><strong>Påskeæg med nougat (6 stk)</strong><br>150 g. marcipan <br>ca. 40 g. nougat<br>150 g. mørk chokolade <br>50 g. lys chokolade &nbsp;</p>
'''

soup = BS(s,'html.parser')
q = soup.find('div', class_='opskriften')
r = q.find('strong')
ingredients = r.parent


In [13]: for tag in ingredients.childGenerator():
    ...:     if tag.name == 'strong':
    ...:         print(tag.text)
    ...:     elif tag.name == 'br':
    ...:         continue
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print(tag)
    ...:         
Påskeæg med nougat (6 stk)
150 g. marcipan 
ca. 40 g. nougat
150 g. mørk chokolade 
50 g. lys chokolade
```

If the `<p>` tag that contains all the ingredients is always the last `<p>` tag in the `div` then you can find it like this.

```
q = soup.find('div', class_='opskriften')
ingredients = q.find_all('p')[-1]
```